# Parallelizing SVM

Tags: svm, parallel-computing

I have a big dataset and implementation of SVM (+ SMO) doesn't support training whole dataset at once, so I have partitioned the dataset into around 20 sets and now its successfully training on all sub-datasets.

Can I combine the training of all the SVMs to have a combined SVM having same effect as training SVM on whole dataset all at once? I want a mathematical proof to support or reject it.
Thanks